# sqlalchemy python postgress problems importing psql module

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

For handling my postgres database with sqlalchemy in python3 I need this import:

```
from psql import Base, db, session
```

But I don't have the module

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psql
```

So i do "sudo pip3 install psycopg2-binary" but that doesn't help.

What module do I need to install to import psql?

Comment: https://analyzingalpha.com/create-price-database-postgresql-sqlalchemy

Comment: Evidently the module is part of their setup - see [here](https://github.com/leosmigel/analyzingalpha/commit/36962979f941da761d8244db37cb81036e80f8ce).

Answer (score -1):

`import psycopg2` instead of psql

[psycopg2 documents](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/)